# Распространение программы, написанной в Qt, на Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, xubuntu

Я написал приложение в `Qt Creator`. Вроде запускается, работает, причем без проблем. Недавно я это же приложение распространял для Windows, поэтому поступил по аналогии - скопировал все необходимые библиотеки (с помощью `lld` определял нужные), затем скопировал файл qt.conf и создал папку `plugins/platforms` (в ней, конечно же, нужные файлы).

Затем я для чистоты эксперимента скачал Live-образ `Xubuntu` той же версии, что и у меня, и запустил приложение. Каковым же было мое разочарование, когда приложение не запустилось! Все время требует 3 бибиотеки:  `libQt5Widgets.so.5`, l`ibQt5Gui.so.5` и `libQt5Core.so.5`. Очень долго клал их в разные места - рядом с бинарником, в `usr/lib` и другие места. Но не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для распространения qt-программ на линуксе рекомендованы три варианта

1. Собрать статическую версию библиотеки и компилировать в ней.
2. Динамическая версия - требует дополнительной установки qt на целевом компе.
3. Самая правоверная - собрать установочный пакет со всеми зависимостями, который в процессе установит все требуемые библиотеки.

Подробности [Qt for Linux/X11 - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html)

Согласно той же документации можно прописать путь к `libQt5Widgets.so.5`, `libQt5Gui.so.5` и `libQt5Core.so.5`, разместив в `main()`:

```
QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("/some/other/path");
//или
QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths(QStringList()<<"/some/other/path");
```

Comment: Все равно не работает. Что это может значить?

Comment: В люнихе  so библиотеки ищутся динамическим загрузчиком только в местах, перечисленных в переменной *LDLIBRARYPATH*. Поэтому размещать их в других **разных местах** просто бессмысленно. Но, как правило, каталоги */lib, /usr/lib* входят в стандартный путь.  Если Вы утверждаете, что размещали библиотеки в */usr/lib*  но загрузчик их не увидел - дело (скорее всего) в версии библиотек.

Comment: Для проверки этой гипотезы попробуйте зайти в каталог */usr/lib* (с этими библиотеками) и выполнить команду (с правами суперпользователя) *ln -s libQt5Widgets.so.5 libQt5Widgets.so*. Т.е. убрать номер версии. Аналогично для остальных библиотек. Посмотрите, что получится... Вам должно выдаться сообщение о том, какие конкретно библиотеки отсутствуют.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте linuxdeployqt:
https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt

Передайте утилите ваш собранный бинарник, она подтянет нужный либы в папку сборки.

P.S. У меня в проекте использовался qwebengineview и при первом запуске он не подтягивался в мой билд. Проблема решалась повторным запуском утилиты в то же место. начиналась ругань что что то уже создано, но после отработки билд становился автономным.